# QGIS 3.22 : Put some custom PNG icons on a map programmatically,to creare a tracker

Tags: qgis, mapping, png

I'm developing a framework using QGIS SDK. It must show some icons updated during time like a tracker. "Some boats on a map with different icons" I have also to perform a selection on an 'icon by mouse click.

I see QgsVertexMarker does not support custom png icons, and I do not see any method for selection, so what is the best way?

The QGIS 3.22 documentation is very poor. I am looking for a solution in Python or C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a [QgsRasterMarkerSymbolLayer](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.22/core/QgsRasterMarkerSymbolLayer.html)

```py
# reference to point layer
lyr = iface.activeLayer()

# get the layer's renderer
r = lyr.renderer()

# get the renderer's symbol
sym = r.symbol()

# create a new Raster Marker Symbol layer
rms = QgsRasterMarkerSymbolLayer()

# configure the data defined override to use a filepath in the 'path' attribute field
prop = QgsProperty()
prop = prop.fromField('path')
rms.setDataDefinedProperty(2, prop)

# pass the raster marker symbol layer to the symbol
sym.appendSymbolLayer(rms)

# optionally remove the original simple marker symbol layer
sym.deleteSymbolLayer(0)

# scale the image
rms.setSize(50)

# update the renderer
lyr.triggerRepaint()
```

[image]

Comment: Ok Thank you ! very much, my problem is that every points must have a different icon, and a different position updated during the time. So probably QGIS doesn't support this feature. I have to create a tracker for boats with different icons ad positions on a map.

Comment: Solution is to subclass QgsMapCanvasItem to create an object and then set on canvas scene.