# Adding markers to the map in standalone PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, markers, standalone

I want to add markers to the map at geographical coordinates, preferably numbered labels as I need to identify different addresses given in a list. Later I want to export the map into PDF using Layouts.

I found this manual - https://www.geodose.com/2018/07/python-qgis-tutorial-drawing-marker.html, but ran into problems. In standalone PyQGIS, I cannot use `iface.mapCanvas()`. When reading https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/canvas.html#id1 about creating canvases I do not understand, whether I can create a canvas, which remains connected to my project so I could see markers in my Print Layout. Rather, it seems layers are added separately to the canvas and a separate object is created.

About adding custom symbols or numbers as my markers, I did find only [QGIS 3.22 : Put some custom PNG icons on a map programmatically,to creare a tracker](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/443410/qgis-3-22-put-some-custom-png-icons-on-a-map-programmatically-to-creare-a-trac), but I don't see a solution to my problem there - code for adding a marker at given geographic coordinates.

It should be something similar to Leaflet's functionality.

Comment: You'll need to explain in a bit more detail what you're trying to do. Rather than adding "markers", you're probably better off creating a new layer and then adding points to that layer - particularly if you then want to create a print layout. Think about how you would do what you want without PyQGIS, and then work out how to automate.

Comment: Without QGIS, I would add numbers ontop of certain adresses, like 1., 2., 3., etc., and then I would add text labels to this print layout telling what each number means. Can point appearance be customized and are they appearing same at different zoom levels of the map?

Comment: @TomBrennan thank you your comment was useful.